# Why is git not working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have installed husky in my project. Then I ran the `precommit` command. Now, when I run the `git` command, it is not working and it's instead asking me **how do you want to open the file**. So, I removed husky using `npm prune` and then removed the hooks folder from `/.git` of the project directory, but still didn't help. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 14):

First, in the built-in terminal, type: `git --version`.

If that command does not work, download and install the latest version of Git. Else, in VS Code's extensions, in the search bar type: `@builtin`. This will list all the built-in extensions in VS Code categorized under different sections. In the 'Features' section look for Git extension. Check if it is disabled. Enable it and your version control should start working.

Answer (score 7):

Uncheck the setting `Require Git User Config` in VS Code.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5):

After reading the other posts with their answers of deleting and reinstalling Git and Github, I discovered that I had the Atom GitHub package installed from prior experiments. I deleted Atom and restarted VSCode and it now works with the Git repo.

Comment: close and open VS Code helped me.

Answer (score 5):

I had a somewhat similar issue - VS Code stopped working with Git (for example: no change detection, problems with fetching from remotes), but I couldn't find what caused this issue (I didn't install Husky like what the OP did).

Inspired by [@user9795515's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269860/2745495), I resolved the problem with Git by **restarting the Git feature in VSC**:

1. Go to *Extensions*
2. In the search bar type *@builtin*
3. Find Git and Git Base features and disable them
4. Restart VS Code
5. Re-enable both features

Answer (score 0):

Try to check from Terminal, if Git command is recognized.
Curently I'm using Powershell terminal.
`git --version` this should be return like this `git version 2.28.0.windows.1`

If that doesn't work then try these steps:

1. Check VS Code Terminal Setting as explained on this link [VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-shells)
2. Update setting.json. My settings would be like this.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "args": ["-NoExit", "-ExecutionPolicy",  "Unrestricted", "-NoProfile", "-File", "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\bootstrap-git.profile.ps1"],
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
    }
```

3. Close Terminal, and then Run Terminal again, and check if Git command is recognized with `git --version`.
4. Additional setting for Powershell to includes Git Command in `bootstrap-git.profile.ps1` file which is used in Point 2.

```
# Start a transcript
#
if (!(Test-Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Transcripts"))
{
    if (!(Test-Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell"))
    {
        $rc = New-Item -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell" -ItemType directory
    }
    $rc = New-Item -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Transcripts" -ItemType directory
}
$curdate = $(get-date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss")
Start-Transcript -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Transcripts\PowerShell_transcript.$curdate.txt"

# Alias Git
#
New-Alias -Name git -Value "$Env:ProgramFiles\Git\bin\git.exe"
```

Alternatively, if you're already installed Git, then try to using Git Bash Terminal in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, however my `git --version` was working on cmd.

I have set up `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` in `PATH` (Windows -> envirorment variable -> PATH). Once I did that I restarted cmd and Visual Studio Code and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. Below is the solution that worked.

1. Open Vscode
2. Ctrl + Shift + P
3. Type 'select default profile'
4. Choose any terminal aside Powershell.

Don't know why powershell isn't working but changing to either CMD and Git bash works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall git and select VS Code as git's default editor.

Answer (score -2):

Try running `git config --global safe.directory *` in your terminal.