# vscode can't seem to find wsl git

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

My vscode suddenly started having issues finding git in WSL2.

Things I've checked:

- It's running in WSL mode.
- Running `which git` in my terminal returns "/usr/bin/git"
- I have the WSL extension by Microsoft (v0.77.0) installed

Other info:

- I'm running Windows 10 (Minor 0, Build 19044, Revision 0)
- I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in WSL2
- I'm aware of [VSCode: use WSL Git instead of Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441830/vscode-use-wsl-git-instead-of-git-for-windows) but that seems to old to be relevant

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but have you tried the obvious, restart vscode, computer etc?  If you have, maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71124362/889742

Comment: Thanks @GonenI ! I did, I should have written that in the list. I figured it out, turns out it was just a bad `.gitconfig`

Comment: what do you see in your Ouput panel's git channels?

Comment: I have the same error. How did you fix your .gitconfig?

Comment: @LeslieK I was lucky in that the error was very a very obvious syntactical error I’m the config. (A fully remember now, but it was something like a missing = sign). Once I fixed it everything worked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had nothing to do with whether git was installed or not. Vscode was saying I didn't have git installed when in fact my `.gitconfig` was misconfigured, causing git to error out.

Comment: So how did you figure out it was a bad `.gitconfig`?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg I was lucky in that the error was very a very obvious syntactical error I’m the config. (A fully remember now, but it was something like a missing = sign). Once I fixed it everything worked again.